# How do I configure background transparency for KDE's terminal?

Tags: command-line, kde, appearance

I got installed kde-plasma desktop but I didn't figured out how to set transparency for kde terminal . I know about gnome terminal that , it will be at preference but I didn't get it here in kde for the terminal .

thank you .

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I guess you mean *Konsole* by the KDE Terminal. Here's how to set background transparency:

1. Click Menu *Settings*
2. Click *Configure Current Profile...* / *Edit Current Profile...*
3. Choose tab *Appearance*
4. Click *Edit...*
   [image: settings window]
5. Choose the background transparency you wish.
6. Enjoy.
   [image: transparent example screenshot]